# Permission Denied when attempting to Parse XML Data on Network Share

Tags: python, windows, xml-parsing, minidom

I'm using minidom in Python to parse some log files in a directory on the network. I can print the list of file names just fine but get the error: 
`IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\\\\10.10.10.80\\logs'`
 
whenever I attempt to parse. Here is my code:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as xml
import os

for filename in os.walk('\\\\10.10.10.80\logs\\'):
    print filename
    doc = xml.parse('\\\\10.10.10.80\logs', filename)

    queue = doc.Element.getElementsByTagName('QueueEntry')

    print queue
```

Any ideas as to why it's shutting me out? I get the same error when attempting to parse files from a local directory too, so it must not have to do with the network. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Tried `chmod()` as suggested by @inspectorG4dget but still got the error. I'm on Win7 accessing the directory of files on a Windows Server 2008 machine. The files are shared, with everyone, and I can open, read and write via Windows Explorer. Here is my `chmod()` code which returned the same error and another `subproccess` snippet that I tried:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as xml
import os, glob, sys, stat

for filename in os.walk('\\\\10.10.10.80\\logs\\'):
    print filename
    os.chmod('\\\\10.10.10.80\\logs\\', stat.S_IRWXO)
    #Also tried other modes, all with the same error
    doc = xml.parse('\\\\10.10.10.80\\logs', filename)
    queue = doc.Element.getElementsByTagName('QueueEntry')
    print queue
```

```
import xml.dom.minidom as xml
import os, sys, stat, subprocess

for filename in os.walk('\\\\10.10.10.80\\logs\\'):
    subprocess.call(['chmod', '-R', '+w', '\\\\10.10.10.80\\logs'])
    print filename
    doc = xml.parse('\\\\10.10.10.80\\logs', filename)
    queue = doc.Element.getElementsByTagName('QueueEntry')
    print queue
```

This returns the error:
 `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Your username does not have permissions to read that file. You need to do a `chmod` and give your username read access to that file. Also, I notice that the file path in your post is contains `'.80\logs'` which I think should be `'.80\\logs'`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Good catch, that is a typo, on both here and my code... I'll give the chmod a try. Thank you!